# functional dependency

Tags: functional-dependencies, 3nf

I am studying about functional dependency for sql and

I got a question.

We have functional dependencies

```
A->B
C->D
CA->E
D->F
```

and

I was trying to figure out whether that is  decomposed relation or not

For example we have two relationship

First = CAEB
Second = CDF

and

I would like to know that these two realationship is decomposition when we use BCNF or 3NF

For my idea,

First and second is not decomposition  for BCNF

becuase
For First,

```
CA -> E
A->B
```

For Second,

```
C->D
D->F
```

Is it right ? (I was searching concept about BCNF and i tried to apply for this question.)

and

I am not really sure how to do for 3NF part....(It seems to be almost same as BCNF but I am not really sure...)

Does anyone know how to do 3NF part ?
thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right. You can checkout the great database lectures from Stanford University here [Introduction to Databases](http://www.db-class.org/course/class/index)

Comment: how do we do for 3NF ?  and I am not really sure the way to access that website...

Comment: You can just register, click on Enroll it's free.